# Jmeter - Plugins behind the proxy

Tags: proxy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I placed plugin manager in "lib\ext" folder and tried to open it showed error:

> java.io.IOException: Repository responded with wrong status code: 407

- Jmeter version - 3.3
- Plugin version - 0.16

Jmeter is invoked from command line by using the following parameters:

`C:\Users\princen\Performance Testing\Software\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\jmeter.bat  -H Proxyserver -P 1234 -u princen -a ***`

Parameters modified as suggested [here](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManagerNetworkConfiguration/)

`JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=Proxyserver -Dhttps.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.proxyUser=princen -Dhttp.proxyPass=***" C:\Users\princen\Performance Testing\Software\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\jmeter.bat`

Above try gives the following error message

> Windows cannot find "JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=Proxyserver -Dhttps.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.proxyUser=princen -Dhttp.proxyPass=***

When I tried to changes command to the following:

`C:\Users\princen\Performance Testing\Software\apache-jmeter-3.3\bin\jmeter.bat -Dhttps.proxyHost=Proxyserver -Dhttps.proxyPort=1234 -Dhttp.proxyUser=princen -Dhttp.proxyPass=***`

I received an error:

> java.io.IOException: Repository responded with wrong status code: 407

Can someone please correct parameters required to load the plugin manager?

Comment: Did you literally wrote `***` in password or real password?

Comment: I can't put in a public forum.

Comment: What is your plugin manger version? There was an issue reported https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/jmeter-plugins/1q4llR4ffew/zqGaUtiIBgAJ

Comment: you specify `proxyHost` and  and `proxyPort` parameters with http**s** suffix, but `proxyUser` and `proxyPass` with http. Those should match

Comment: Its not working even after the suggested changes.

Answer (score 1):

after several days of struggling I found the solution for this :) It's a combination of all suggested things here. So to be absolutely plain:

Take your jmeter.bat (Im running on Win)

1. Locate this line (shold be almost at the end):
   `%JM_START% "%JM_LAUNCH%" %ARGS% %JVM_ARGS% -jar "%JMETER_BIN%ApacheJMeter.jar" %JMETER_CMD_LINE_ARGS%`
2. Add this line BEFORE it (change your host,port,user (if applied),password (if applied)). Yes don't use quotes in there!:
   `JVM_ARGS=-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=john -Dhttps.proxyPassword=yourpassword -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=john -Dhttp.proxyPassword=yourpassword`
3. Save it and run jmeter.bat -> By doing this my plugin manager finally works!

Comment: I am glad to see a positive after 7 years

Comment: 'JVM_ARGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Thanks! You don't need to edit jmeter.bat. You can do in cmd: set JVM_ARGS=-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=john -Dhttps.proxyPassword=yourpassword -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=john -Dhttp.proxyPassword=yourpassword

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you use last version of jmeter-plugins download manager.

Regarding your parameters, you're mixing different configurations, just set (for both http and https):

> JVM_ARGS="-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttps.proxyUser=john -Dhttps.proxyPass=password -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=john -Dhttp.proxyPass=password"

Where password is your real password.

Comment: I have changed the parameters to https and tried, but still its not working. I use the latest plugin manager(Version - 0.16)

Answer (score 0):

None of above methods working for me. Its really tough to work with Java(due to Loadrunner background). I added Ultimate thread alone and its working fine.

Thank you all for your inputs..

Answer (score 0):

JMeter is using the official proxy configuration from Oracle (like here: https://memorynotfound.com/configure-http-proxy-settings-java/)

The problem is that the jmeter documentation is wrong about the password parameter: it should be **http.proxyPassword** not **http.proxyPass**.

Also you must use the **https.** properties for secured urls you want to access using the proxy. And the **http.** properties for non secured.